# Heroku PostgreSQL changing sortable_list POST?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm having the oddest problem with PostgreSQL - can anybody help?

My app allows users to create objects, which are then listed on a page. I followed the Ryan Bates Railscasts [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists) to make them sortable, which works fine on my system.

So locally, using this code:

```
  def sort
    params[:faqs].each_with_index do |id, index|
      Object.update_all(['position=?', index+1], ['id=?', id])
    end
    render :nothing => true
  end
```

I get this output on the POST request:

> Started POST "/users/sort_object" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Dec 06
>   16:43:52 +0100 2011   Processing by ObjectController#sort as JS
>   Parameters:
>   {"authenticity_token"=>"#####################",
>   "_"=>"", "faqs"=>["5", "1389", "11", "1350", "147", "849", "932",
>   "1260", "23", "10", "1261"]}   AREL (1.8ms)  UPDATE "objects" SET
>   position=1 WHERE (id='5')   AREL (1.2ms)  UPDATE "objects" SET
>   position=2 WHERE (id='1389')   AREL (2.9ms)  UPDATE "objects" SET
>   position=3 WHERE (id='11')   AREL (3.3ms)  UPDATE "objects" SET
>   position=4 WHERE (id='1350')   AREL (1.4ms)  UPDATE "objects" SET
>   position=5 WHERE (id='147')   AREL (1.5ms)  UPDATE "objects" SET
>   position=6 WHERE (id='849')   AREL (1.2ms)  UPDATE "objects" SET
>   position=7 WHERE (id='932')   AREL (1.5ms)  UPDATE "objects" SET
>   position=8 WHERE (id='1260')   AREL (1.5ms)  UPDATE "objects" SET
>   position=9 WHERE (id='23')   AREL (2.0ms)  UPDATE "objects" SET
>   position=10 WHERE (id='10')   AREL (1.9ms)  UPDATE "objects" SET
>   position=11 WHERE (id='1261') Rendered text template (0.0ms)

I have tested this locally with multiple users and changing the order on one doesn't appears to interfere with the others' Objects - as you can see, the DB is only inserting the position for the object ID's listed for that user.

However, when I look at the DB as stored on Heroku, something weird is happening. I end up with users that have multiple Objects with position=1, which appears to be caused by other users changing their positioning.

Can anyone help? Is there a way I can debug this (I don't have a dedicated server on Heroku, so I can't stream logs)? Anyone know what might be causing it?

Hope this is clear, shout if not...

Comment: you can tail the logs, heroku logs -f from the CLI although you may need to bump up the logging level and upgrade to expanding logging (it's free) to enable tailing.

Comment: This just gives me server requests sadly, it doesn't allow me to see what's actually being posted to the database as the CLI does? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial is meant for just one user (i.e. the site administrator) using the sorting functionality. You need to apply a different solution (store each user's sort order in session or something).

Comment: This answer is absolutely correct, I figured it out half an hour ago. Just to expand: When users deleted an object, the acts_as_list plugin calls a method which decrements the 'position' on everything below it, to keep it in order. Of course, with multiple positions, it was affecting everything regardless of the user. It had nothing to do with PostgreSQL at all and I was able to reproduce it using a local DB - apologies for the badly worded question!